# Symfony2 file upload get original file name

Tags: php, symfony

I am unable to retrieve the originalName during a file upload.

print_r($request->file) returns the following:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag Object
(
    [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [form_name] => Array
                (
                    [backgroundImageFile] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
                        (
                            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
                            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => bg_image.jpg
                            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
                            [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 65045
                            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
                            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpsU3X7a
                            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpsU3X7a
                        )

                )

        )

)


echo "<br /> Name= ".$this->getRequest()->files['backgroundImageFile']->getClientOriginalName();
```

Returns:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a
>   non-object in ../path to the controller

So, how do I get the OriginalName?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the get() method on the FileBag, rather than array access.

E.g.,

```
$this->getRequest()->files->get("backgroundImageFile")->getClientOriginalName();
```

Alternatively, if it makes sense in your scenario, use a form upload, then access the uploaded file as form data.

Comment: I still get the Fatal error: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object in ../path to the controller.  I just need to get the Orginal File Name before the form is submitted

Comment: @kewpe20 Before the form is submitted the file isn't uploaded. The upload happens on form submit, so before then there's nothing to get the name of.

Comment: If you can put your code up somewhere for me to take a look, I'll see what's going on in your specific instance.